# Ext.tree.TreeLoader is not a constructor error

Tags: extjs, extjs4, treepanel, extjs-mvc

I'm new to Extjs4.In Extjs4 loader not working when i use  `loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader()`
. it showing the error like "Ext.tree.TreeLoader is not a constructor". it works fine in extjs older versions.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In extjs 4 the component Ext.tree.TreeLoader ist not supported anymore, For the loader config of a treepanel now you can use Ext.ComponentLoader but i would suggest you rather use Ext.data.TreeStore which you can configure to load your data similar to Ext.tree.TreeLoader .. for documentation use the extjs 4 api .. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/docs/#/api/Ext.data.TreeStore

also you can check some examples they have :
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/#sample-6

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/tree/check-tree.js